# Random latch period of 555

Tags: 555, latch, random

I've designed a dice circuit, simulated it in Proteus (which worked) and got the PCBs manufactured. A problem I'm facing on the real thing is that if the button is pressed normally (e.g. for as long as you'd press a key on your keyboard), the "roll time" is always the same, resulting in the same number showing at the end of the roll. Holding the button for longer than what I assume is the C6 charge time results in the expected randmomness.

Is there a way to randomise the "time on" of the 555 latch without having to get new boards manufactured?

Ideas I've had are using an LDR or thermistor to somewhat randomise the time.

Here is the circuit diagram in question:
[image: Dice circuit]

Comment: The faster you make the second 555 run the more random it will get.

Comment: Make C6 ten times smaller.

Comment: I've replaced R5 with a 100k resistor and while more random, it seems to bias to 5 or 3. I guess changing C6 and making the "time on" shorter would rely more on the randomness of the time the button is pressed for? Edit: some more playing and I've decided that the 100k resistor makes it random enough. It seems that the 5/3 bias was just temporary. It definitely seems more random now. Thanks a lot